# How to Make alert fire only once when long/short? common solution not working

Tags: alert, repeat, pine-script

Problem: getting alert firing on every candle condition: early_sell_signal

I am trying this method to prevent alert when already bearish

```
bearishPosMem = false
bearishPosMem := bearish ? true : bullish ? false : bearishPosMem[1]

early_sell_signal = bearish and not(bearishPosMem[1])
plotshape(early_sell_signal, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="EARLY SELL",textcolor=white)
```

Im getting error: Script could not be translated from: |B|bearishPosMem := bearish ? true

I have used this method in a another simple script without error. So I imagine the error is forced from another part of the script. (Yes its a mess atm, I'm still merging 2 scripts into one and other code still yet to be entered)

```
study("Ichimoku Alerts by Trusty777", shorttitle="ICH Alerts", overlay=true)

//inputs
TKlength=input(9, "Conversion-line Length", minval=1)
KJlength=input(26, "Base-line Length", minval=1)
CSHSlength=input(26, "Lagging Length/Horizontal Shift", minval=1)
SBlength=input(52, "LeadingpanB Length", minval=1)
SAlength=input(26,"LeadingpanA Length", minval=1)
early_buy = input(true, title="Early Buy")
early_sell = input(true, title="Early Sell")

TK=avg(lowest(TKlength), highest(TKlength))
KJ=avg(lowest(KJlength), highest(KJlength))
CS=close
SB=avg(lowest(SBlength), highest(SBlength))
SA=avg(TK,KJ)

plot(TK, linewidth=2, color=blue, title="Conversion")
plot(KJ, linewidth=2, color=red, title="Base")

plot(CS, offset=-CSHSlength, linewidth=2, color=#DDA0DD, title="Lagging Span")

SenkouA=plot(SA, offset=CSHSlength,  linewidth=1, color=green, title="LeadingSpanA")
SenkouB=plot(SB, offset=CSHSlength, linewidth=1, color=purple, title="LeadingSpanB")

fill(SenkouA, SenkouB, color = SA > SB ? green : red)

middle(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))

// Ichimoku Components
tenkan = middle(TKlength)
kijun = middle(KJlength)
senkouA = avg(tenkan, kijun)
senkouB = middle(SBlength)

ss_high = max(senkouA[SBlength-1], senkouB[SBlength-1])
ss_low = min(senkouA[SBlength-1], senkouB[SBlength-1])

// Entry/Exit Signals
tk_cross_bull = TK > KJ
tk_cross_bear = TK < KJ
cs_cross_bull = mom(close, CSHSlength-1) > 0
cs_cross_bear = mom(close, CSHSlength-1) < 0
price_above_kumo = close > ss_high
price_below_kumo = close < ss_low

bullish = tk_cross_bull and cs_cross_bull and price_above_kumo
bearish = tk_cross_bear and cs_cross_bear and price_below_kumo

buy=crossover(KJ,SB[26])
plotshape(buy, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="BUY",textcolor=white)
sell=crossover(SB[26],KJ)
plotshape(sell, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="SELL",textcolor=white)
          
early_buy_signal =crossover(TK,SB[26]) and (TK>KJ) and (close >SB and SA)
plotshape(early_buy_signal, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="EARLY BUY",textcolor=white)


bearishPosMem = false
bearishPosMem := bearish ? true : bullish ? false : bearishPosMem[1]

early_sell_signal = bearish and not(bearishPosMem[1])
plotshape(early_sell_signal, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="EARLY SELL",textcolor=white)



    
//ALERT FOR AUTOVIEW TRADE
alertcondition(buy, title='BUY', message='BUY')
alertcondition(sell, title='SELL', message='SELL')
study("Ichimoku Alerts by Trusty777", shorttitle="ICH Alerts", overlay=true)

//inputs
TKlength=input(9, "Conversion-line Length", minval=1)
KJlength=input(26, "Base-line Length", minval=1)
CSHSlength=input(26, "Lagging Length/Horizontal Shift", minval=1)
SBlength=input(52, "LeadingpanB Length", minval=1)
SAlength=input(26,"LeadingpanA Length", minval=1)
early_buy = input(true, title="Early Buy")
early_sell = input(true, title="Early Sell")

TK=avg(lowest(TKlength), highest(TKlength))
KJ=avg(lowest(KJlength), highest(KJlength))
CS=close
SB=avg(lowest(SBlength), highest(SBlength))
SA=avg(TK,KJ)

plot(TK, linewidth=2, color=blue, title="Conversion")
plot(KJ, linewidth=2, color=red, title="Base")

plot(CS, offset=-CSHSlength, linewidth=2, color=#DDA0DD, title="Lagging Span")

SenkouA=plot(SA, offset=CSHSlength,  linewidth=1, color=green, title="LeadingSpanA")
SenkouB=plot(SB, offset=CSHSlength, linewidth=1, color=purple, title="LeadingSpanB")

fill(SenkouA, SenkouB, color = SA > SB ? green : red)

middle(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))

// Ichimoku Components
tenkan = middle(TKlength)
kijun = middle(KJlength)
senkouA = avg(tenkan, kijun)
senkouB = middle(SBlength)

ss_high = max(senkouA[SBlength-1], senkouB[SBlength-1])
ss_low = min(senkouA[SBlength-1], senkouB[SBlength-1])

// Entry/Exit Signals
tk_cross_bull = TK > KJ
tk_cross_bear = TK < KJ
cs_cross_bull = mom(close, CSHSlength-1) > 0
cs_cross_bear = mom(close, CSHSlength-1) < 0
price_above_kumo = close > ss_high
price_below_kumo = close < ss_low

bullish = tk_cross_bull and cs_cross_bull and price_above_kumo
bearish = tk_cross_bear and cs_cross_bear and price_below_kumo

buy=crossover(KJ,SB[26])
plotshape(buy, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="BUY",textcolor=white)
sell=crossover(SB[26],KJ)
plotshape(sell, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="SELL",textcolor=white)
          
early_buy_signal =crossover(TK,SB[26]) and (TK>KJ) and (close >SB and SA)
plotshape(early_buy_signal, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="EARLY BUY",textcolor=white)


bearishPosMem = false
bearishPosMem := bearish ? true : bullish ? false : bearishPosMem[1]

early_sell_signal = bearish and not(bearishPosMem[1])
plotshape(early_sell_signal, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="EARLY SELL",textcolor=white)



    
//ALERT FOR AUTOVIEW TRADE
alertcondition(buy, title='BUY', message='BUY')
alertcondition(sell, title='SELL', message='SELL')
study("Ichimoku Alerts by Trusty777", shorttitle="ICH Alerts", overlay=true)

//inputs
TKlength=input(9, "Conversion-line Length", minval=1)
KJlength=input(26, "Base-line Length", minval=1)
CSHSlength=input(26, "Lagging Length/Horizontal Shift", minval=1)
SBlength=input(52, "LeadingpanB Length", minval=1)
SAlength=input(26,"LeadingpanA Length", minval=1)
early_buy = input(true, title="Early Buy")
early_sell = input(true, title="Early Sell")

TK=avg(lowest(TKlength), highest(TKlength))
KJ=avg(lowest(KJlength), highest(KJlength))
CS=close
SB=avg(lowest(SBlength), highest(SBlength))
SA=avg(TK,KJ)

plot(TK, linewidth=2, color=blue, title="Conversion")
plot(KJ, linewidth=2, color=red, title="Base")

plot(CS, offset=-CSHSlength, linewidth=2, color=#DDA0DD, title="Lagging Span")

SenkouA=plot(SA, offset=CSHSlength,  linewidth=1, color=green, title="LeadingSpanA")
SenkouB=plot(SB, offset=CSHSlength, linewidth=1, color=purple, title="LeadingSpanB")

fill(SenkouA, SenkouB, color = SA > SB ? green : red)

middle(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))

// Ichimoku Components
tenkan = middle(TKlength)
kijun = middle(KJlength)
senkouA = avg(tenkan, kijun)
senkouB = middle(SBlength)

ss_high = max(senkouA[SBlength-1], senkouB[SBlength-1])
ss_low = min(senkouA[SBlength-1], senkouB[SBlength-1])

// Entry/Exit Signals
tk_cross_bull = TK > KJ
tk_cross_bear = TK < KJ
cs_cross_bull = mom(close, CSHSlength-1) > 0
cs_cross_bear = mom(close, CSHSlength-1) < 0
price_above_kumo = close > ss_high
price_below_kumo = close < ss_low

bullish = tk_cross_bull and cs_cross_bull and price_above_kumo
bearish = tk_cross_bear and cs_cross_bear and price_below_kumo

buy=crossover(KJ,SB[26])
plotshape(buy, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="BUY",textcolor=white)
sell=crossover(SB[26],KJ)
plotshape(sell, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="SELL",textcolor=white)
          
early_buy_signal =crossover(TK,SB[26]) and (TK>KJ) and (close >SB and SA)
plotshape(early_buy_signal, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="EARLY BUY",textcolor=white)


bearishPosMem = false
bearishPosMem := bearish ? true : bullish ? false : bearishPosMem[1]

early_sell_signal = bearish and not(bearishPosMem[1])
plotshape(early_sell_signal, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="EARLY SELL",textcolor=white)



    
//ALERT FOR AUTOVIEW TRADE
alertcondition(buy, title='BUY', message='BUY')
alertcondition(sell, title='SELL', message='SELL')
```

Comment: You have posted the same code twice, please do the needful

Comment: Thank you, I understand that now. How can do the same affect to the plotshape? As its plotting every candle too

Comment: Also as far as I can tell you cant use alerts on strategy

Comment: of course you can add alerts in a strategy. In true sense, alerts are most useful to directly get buy and sell signals (to generate actual orders) without having to look at the chart

Comment: I have alert conditions which work fine in study: I have BUY and SELL options in the alert pop-up window. With the strategy conversion there is no option in the pop-up alert window. Yes it does alert for strategy LONG/SHORT, but what if I want more options for alerts for different conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong way of doing it. You are getting multiple alerts because the conditions are being fulfilled multiple times.

Instead of `study()`, use `strategy()`. It will look something like this

```
//Your calculations here
longCondition = //Buy conditions here

if(longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Buy signal id",true,1)

shortCondition = //Sell conditions here

if(shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Sell signal id",false,1)

//Your alerts here
```

You can also program individual exit based on profit or loss or simply choose to change direction when opposite trade triggers(this is what is happening here)